# Unable to determine malloc argument for array of strings in node

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, nodes

I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how to allocate memory for each string in an array of strings in a node, as follows:

```
typedef struct node {
    char args[10][20];
    struct node *previous;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

Node * createNode(void) {
    Node *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        newNode->args[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
    }
    return newNode;
}
```

This causes the following error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[20]’ from type ‘char *’
   newNode->args[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Similarly, when I tried `malloc(sizeof(char *))`, I received this error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[20]’ from type ‘char *’
   newNode->args[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

I thought I had begun to understand pointers in C, but now I'm extremely confused. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to allocate memory to char[10][20]. As this means you have already enough memory allocated to 10 char arrays of size 20 each.

Comment: In any case `malloc(sizeof(char))` would allocate one byte of memory.

Comment: And do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: Indeed, in this case the error was still generated but in C casting the return from `malloc` can hide an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already allocated memory for args in

```
char args[10][20]
```

it throws an error when reallocating memory for it.

Instead you could change to:

```
char **args
```

And then allocate memory using malloc:

```
newNode->args = (char**)malloc(sizeof(*char)*10)
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    newNode->args[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
}
```

Assuming you need a size of 20 string.

Comment: Please show how, as the string length was never in OP's code attempts.

Comment: And ... why? If you *indeed* want fixed-size strings, allocating them separately is just applied waste of resources.

Comment: and btw, your wording is so inaccurate, it strives to be plain wrong. `char args[10][20]` in OP's code doesn't allocate anything, it declares a member and is allocated when the containing struct is allocated. Reallocation isn't forbidden, but you can't assign a "row" of a 2d-array (because it's not a pointer) and in general you can't reallocate *part* of a dynamically allocated object.

Comment: I would prefer `if((newNode->args[i] = malloc(20)) == NULL) {...}` that's three corrections

Comment: True .. I just gave the work around for the error given in the question .. But in order to use malloc explicitly .. args can be declared completely as an pointer of arrays(**args)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to give an answer here, there's probably one thing to clarify first:

an array **is not** a pointer.

This is a quite common misconception because an array automatically *decays* as a pointer when used as a function argument and it is implicitly convertible to a pointer. Still it is NOT the same.

So given this, look at your structure. You don't have any pointers to `char` in there. There's just no need to allocate anything for `args`, because your `struct node` already includes `10 * 20` bytes of space for the member `args`.